# Semi-consistent Long Sessions Versus Regular Short Sessions

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-recommendation

I've noticed it's really difficult for me to be consistent, even with short meditation. I'm thus hesitating between:

- 10 min sessions every day
- 40 min sessions every 2 or 3 days

Which of these seems more beneficial?

Comment: Tried doing at least 10 and more on days when you feel like it?

Answer (score 1):

Long sits everyday is the most optimal.  As I've written you time and time again, you have to do the work.  There are no shortcuts.  There is only the hard way.  Stop looking for excuses.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience, and also on [some of the research on habits](https://charlesduhigg.com/books/the-power-of-habit/), short but consistent sessions might be better to help ease you into longer sessions. If your brain gradually transfers the act of starting your meditation from the willpower-related regions to the habit-related regions, and you start observing the benefits and pleasure derived from short sits done consistently over time, my hope is you'll find less and less resistance to longer sessions.

In my experience, I've obtained the best results if I sit at approximately the same time, in the same place in my routine during the day (e.g. right after waking up and hearing a [short Dhamma talk](https://www.dhammatalks.org/mp3_short_index_current.html), or at the end of my work day, to help me process the events of the day).

I hope this is helpful. Metta.